# Necesito que en el ultimo elemento del array se cumpla una condicion

Tags: c#, array

Es una suma de derivadas, y se le va agregando el signo "*+*" cada vez que la resuelve. Pero en el último elemento no se tiene que agregar el signo "*+*". Por favor, ayuda con eso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Elias, edita la publicación para poner el código en formato de texto. De esta forma será más fácil poder copiarlo localmente y hacer pruebas. Por lo demás, ¿qué probaste? Suena como a "por favor debuggad mi código" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(i<partes.Lenght-1){
      funciones += x +'+'
} else {
      funciones += x
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me funciono!!!

Answer (score 1):

Cuando te encuentras en la situación de que quieres que todos los elementos sean procesados de cierta manera excepto el último, a veces es útil invertir la situación, es decir que todos los elementos sean procesados igual excepto el primero.

Un ejemplo, digamos que tienes un array `var array = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };` y quieres que este se muestre como una sola cadena separada por comas así `"1,2,3,4"` (solo como demostración porque lo mismo se podría lograr con `string.Join(",", array)`)

En un primer intento tal vez uno haría algo como esto:

```
string result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) 
{
    result += array[i] + ",";
}

// ""
// 1,
// 1, 2,
// 1, 2, 3,
// 1, 2, 3, 4,
```

pero esto te devolvería `"1,2,3,4,"` con una coma extra al final y la primera solución que viene a la mente es que el último elemento sea la excepción pero te presento una alternativa:

```
string result = array[0].ToString();
for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    result += "," + array[i];
}

// 1
// 1 ,2
// 1 ,2 ,3
// 1 ,2 ,3 ,4
```

y esto te devolvería el resultado esperado `"1,2,3,4"` porque ahora el primer elemento es el que tratamos diferente.  Con esto evitas tener que incluir un `if` dentro del `for` lo que hace que el código sea más limpio.